# Loading a class at runtime

Tags: java, ikvm

I have some code which loads the class at runtime:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

But there seems to be issues with this and IKVM - I was wondering if there were any alternative ways to achieve the above in my Java program or if anyone knew on why that might cause issued with ikvm?

Thanks

sorry - i didnt no how to find out, its taken me ages to get this far! This is caught in the Exception e catch statement and i am pretty sure its thrown by the line posted above

> classname IKVM.NativeCode.java.lang.Class Filename null Method name
>   forName0 Line number -1 classname java.lang.Class Filename Class.java
>   Method name forName0 Line number -2 classname java.lang.Class Filename
>   Class.java Method name forName Line number 287 classname Test Filename
>   Test.java Method name init Line number 50 classname Test Filename
>   Test.java Method name isPDFAvailable Line number 24 classname
>   cli.Analytical_Report.Form1 Filename Form1.cs Method name hasGains
>   Line number 296 classname cli.Analytical_Report.Form1 Filename
>   Form1.cs Method name determineAvailableData Line number 209 classname
>   cli.Analytical_Report.Form1 Filename Form1.cs Method name consumeFile
>   Line number 71 classname cli.Analytical_Report.Form1 Filename Form1.cs
>   Method name btnSelectFile_Click Line number 49 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Control Filename null Method name OnClick
>   Line number -1 classname cli.System.Windows.Forms.Button Filename null
>   Method name OnClick Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Button Filename null Method name OnMouseUp
>   Line number -1 classname cli.System.Windows.Forms.Control Filename
>   null Method name WmMouseUp Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Control Filename null Method name WndProc
>   Line number -1 classname cli.System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase Filename
>   null Method name WndProc Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Button Filename null Method name WndProc Line
>   number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Control$ControlNativeWindow Filename null
>   Method name OnMessage Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Control$ControlNativeWindow Filename null
>   Method name WndProc Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow Filename null Method name
>   DebuggableCallback Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods Filename null Method name
>   DispatchMessageW Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Application$ComponentManager Filename null
>   Method name
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
>   Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Application$ThreadContext Filename null
>   Method name RunMessageLoopInner Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Application$ThreadContext Filename null
>   Method name RunMessageLoop Line number -1 classname
>   cli.System.Windows.Forms.Application Filename null Method name Run
>   Line number -1 classname cli.Analytical_Report.Program Filename
>   Program.cs Method name Main Line number 18 classname
>   cli.System.AppDomain Filename null Method name _nExecuteAssembly Line
>   number -1 classname cli.System.AppDomain Filename null Method name
>   ExecuteAssembly Line number -1 classname
>   cli.Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc Filename null
>   Method name RunUsersAssembly Line number -1

Comment: "seems to be issues" means **what** exactly? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't compiled (would converted be the right term for what IKVM does?) the jar containing the OracleDriver?

Comment: how would i be able ot tell if that was the case or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's the first time I hear about ikvm, but I will try to help.

First, another way to load the JDBC driver is with

`DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());`

Anyhow, I have read in the ikvm website that you have to convert your JARs to DLLs using the command ikvmc. Did you already convert the Oracle driver JAR to a DLL? And:are you sure you have make the classes in this JAR/DLL available to the program? (Whatever equivalent there is for the Java classpath)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Different database format and JDBC driver, but it will work for you with slight modification for oracle and oracle driver (full Namespaces for clarity purposes):

```
java.lang.Class.forName(typeof(org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName);
java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in the [IKVM wiki for ClassLoader](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader) or described your problem better.